# Git push master branch to secondary remote

Tags: git

I have an existing git repository hosted on my company's online git account. I now want to set up a second remote within my client's online git account. I want to keep my company's repository as the primary day-to-day means of sharing code and the client's one just with the master branch for the current releases.

I have used

```
git remote add <clientName> <clientRepoUrl>
```

to add the new remote in my git config file.

I can use

```
git push <clientName> --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
```

to push the whole repo to the new  remote.

But what if I omit the `--all` parameter? How will the merge commits to the master branch show up? Will this actually work properly?

Comment: Yes. When you push a single branch, all commits comprising the history of that branch are pushed to the remote.

Comment: @Leon do you mean when I use the `--all` parameter?

Comment: No, I meant pushing just a single branch, e.g. `git push <clientName> master`. `git push <clientName>` (without a *refspec*) may or may not result in pushing a single branch (depends on your `remote.<clientName>.push` setting).

Comment: When you use the `--all` parameter you're essentially telling git to push all known branches on your local machine over to remote. Saying that all commits that happened on said branches will be push as well - if it's a merge commit you'll most likely see it on your second remote repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what if I omit the --all parameter?

You can simply push only `master` (`git push <clientName> master`) to the second remote repo.
That will include all commits accessible from `master`, including the merge commits parents.

```
x--x--x--x--M --x (master)
    \      /
     y----y       (branchY)
```

Pushing `master` only would push `y` commits, even though the reference `branchY` itself would not be pushed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's fine, I don't mind the commits showing, just as long as their branches view does not show every single feature branch we've made.

Comment: @MatthewDresser yes, since you are not using `--all`, you don't push any other branch name.